# Yammer Rest API for posting status

Tags: jquery, yammer

i am new to yammer. i want to post a status on yammer using Yammer RESTAPI.
as far i have this code

```
yam.platform.request({
    url: "https://api.yammer.com/api/v1/messages.json",
    method: "POST",
    data: {
        "body" : "message body",
        "group_id": "group id",
        "topic1": "topic1",
        "og_url": "http://www.google.com"
    },
    success: function (result) {
        alert("success");
        console.dir(result);
    },
    error: function (result) {
        alert("There was some error");
        console.dir(result);
    }
)};
```

this code post the status on yammer but its showing also alert box that written in

```
error: function(result){
   alert("There was some error");
   console.dir(result);
}
```

i also change url value -

```
url: "messages.json",
```

but the problem remain same.

can anyone know how this will work..???

Answer (score 2):

Having a look at our code, it seems we only pass in the resource and not the full url (see below)

```
yam.platform.request(
{
    url: "messages/private.json",
    method: "GET",
    success: function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    },
    error: function (response) {
        alert("There was an error with the request.");
    }
});
```